# How to understand which UITableViewCell has been selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list of `NSString`s stored in an `NSMutableArray`, each value in the `NSMutableArray` has been assigned to a `UITableViewCell`. Using the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

How do I figure out which cell was selected. I'm looking for some kind of value through `NSIndexPath` or any other method to change the icon of a `UITableViewCell` when it is selected. After I know which cell has been selected, I'd reassign the cell to the new image, and then reload the data using: `[self.homeworkTable reloadData]`.

I'm looking for some kind of simple return value, like `0` if the first cell is selected, etc. I've tried utilizing the `NSIndexPath` with no luck, as an `NSIndexPath` is not an `NSString`. How would I go about doing this?

**EDIT**

I understand the answer may already be on Stack Overflow, I simply haven't found it, and redirecting me to the answer would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for NSIndexPath??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it directly `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (that's the whole point!) using `indexPath.row`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                        didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      int index = indexPath.row;
  //....
```

It will match the index of your datasource array.

Sometimes you will need to get it from outside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` deleguate method, you can do it the following way:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.homeworkTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
int index = indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: This is my only objection: while this is what I'm looking for, if I wanted the take the cells location in the list and use its value to replace an object in another NSMutableArray, how would I go about doing that? I'm looking to get an `int`. I improperly implied that I wanted a `NSString` to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should use indexPath.row, this gets you the row that you selected in this tableview.

You should also check out the documentation on NSIndexPath:

https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html